# How to create facade for singleton in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, facade

I want to create a facade for a singleton that I'v defined in ServiceProvider:

```
$this->app->singleton('\ActivityLogger\ActivityLoggerInterface', '\ActivityLogger\ActivityLogger');
```

How can I have something like this in my code:

```
Logger::log($data)
```

thanks

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Im using Laravel 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version **5.5** Laravel makes it possible to use real-time facades: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/facades#real-time-facades.

In order to make it work, you need to prepend the **use** statement that imports your class with **Facades\**:

```
<?php
use Facades\ActivityLogger\ActivityLogger as Logger;

//...and then in your code
Logger::debug($data);
```